# deploy symfony project with capifony after successfull jenkins build

Tags: symfony, jenkins, capifony

I am working on a symfony2 project, and I am running jenkins on my production server, so every time i push to bitbucket it triggers a jenkins job and do the build in `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/job_name/workspace`and it build successfully.
Now i would like to integrate capifony in all of this but i have no clue, i tried how to configure it.

i have the following error when i try to do a "cap deploy" :

```
Please specify the name of your application, set :application, 'foo'
POST BUILD TASK : FAILURE
```

here is my deploy.rb file :

```
set :application, "myapp"
set :domain,      "mywebsite.com"
set :deploy_to,   "/tmp/deploy"
set :app_path,    "app"
set :use_sudo,    false

set :scm, :none

set :repository, "."
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, \
or `none`

set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain, :primary => true       # This may be the same as your\
 `Web` server

set  :use_composer,   true
set  :update_vendors, true

set  :keep_releases,  3

# Be more verbose by uncommenting the following line
# logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

Thank you.